# Does web2py ajax() function really work with onchange event of <input type=file>?

Tags: html, ajax, forms, file-upload, web2py

In my web2py application, I need to process a file name from an `<input type="file" />` field before uploading it. This processing will analyse the file name with regular expressions and fill other form fields prior to allowing the user to submit the form.

My first step is to get the file name in order to process it. And till now, I failed to get it. According to my interpretation of the web2py documentation, I found that the `ajax()` function should do the trick.

Here are my code chunks.
View:

```
<form>File to upload:
    <input name="zefilename" type="file" onchange="ajax('{{=URL('default', 'analyse_version_data')}}', ['zefilename'], 'target')"/>
    <!-- Other fields go here -->
    <div id="target"></div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
def analyse_version_data():
    filename = request.vars.zefilename
    return P(filename)
```

If my input type is not `type="file"`, then it works just like a charm and the input value is displayed in the target `div`.

But if `type="file"` is present, I can't get anything. The `request.vars` stays empty: `<Storage {'_vars': <Storage {}>,...`

I'm probably missing something, but I can't figure out what...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is attempting to send the whole file via Ajax rather than just sending the filename. To send just the filename, don't use the second argument of the `ajax()` function, but instead add the filename to the query string of the Ajax URL:

```
<form>File to upload:
    <input name="zefilename" type="file"
           onchange='ajax("{{=URL('default', 'analyze_version_data')}}?filename=" +
                          encodeURIComponent(jQuery(this).val()), [], "target");' />
    <!-- Other fields go here -->
    <div id="target"></div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
def analyse_version_data():
    return P(request.vars.filename)
```